# cvsweb is showing a wrong update date of updated files

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cvs

i've installed cvs (1.12.13-MirDebian-8 (client/server)) on ubuntu 12.04 and everythink is working fine except that the wrong date is being shown in the cvsweb.
The server itself is properlly configured with ntp.

i. e. a file is updated daily at 7:00AM. Saying **Fr Oct 24 at 7:00:00 2014**. On cvsweb it will shows **Thu Oct 23 15:00:xx 2014**. It seems like cvsweb has a delay of ~16 hours.

How can i correct this?

Thx a lot

Comment: Could be a time zone issue.

Comment: Thx Andrew!
I found in **/etc/cvsweb/cvsweb.conf** following line **@mytz=(...)**. Uncommited the line with my settings and it was working